# Decrementing Value should Stop with Zero

Tags: iphone, xcode, label

Hello! I have a little problem I was hoping the community could help me with.

1. In `CounterviewController`, I have one label and two Buttons "Add" and "Sub". By pressing the Sub button it decrements the value normally but I need to stop with 0 (don't go below zero to -1,-2,-3,-4).
2. Then I need to display the `countLabel` value into the `PreviousView` label. Can you please help me?

Here's my code:

```
(IBAction)decrementNumber:(id)sender
 {
    number--;
    [currentNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
 }
```

Could you please point out where my error is?

Thanks in Advance,

Padmavathi CP.

Comment: **if (number > 0) number--;**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first question, only decrement and display if the number is greater than zero:

```
-(IBAction)decrementNumber:(id)sender
 {
    if (number > 0) {
        number--;
        [currentNumber setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
    }
 }
```

For your second question, the method may well depend on your object types. For example, for transfers between two `NSTextField` objects (or others based on `NSControl`), you could use something like:

```
[previousView setStringValue: [countLabel stringValue]];
```

Comment: :Thanks for your great answer.But i cant get the answer of my second question.Please do the needful.

Comment: @Padma, you haven't  provided enough information for anything other than a general answer. What are the types of the two controls you want to transfer the information to and from?

Comment: I Kept two class and Label
1.ItemdetailViewcontroller, IBOutlet UILabel*countLbl;

2.CountItemViewController, IBOutlet UILabel currentNumber;


Here,i Kept countLbl in (First Class).I need to display the value of my (second-class)currentNumber value to the countLbl which have been changing the counter value.(ie)that incrementing and decrementing value by pressing the navigation button from 2nd view to 1st.

Comment: @Padma: Then it sounds like you need a getter method in your second class to return the currentNumber string so it can be called for setting countLbl in the first class (with a setter method). You could probably avoid one of those depending one which class is doing the driving of the transfer (if the driving class is the one containing countLvl, obviously you could get at that directly rather than through a setter) but I'd still prefer the setter/getter pair even then, simply because it's proper encapsulation.